# How to accumulate some values within a column based on information in another column from the same data file ?

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk

I have a data file looks like:

```
c1.11   SNP1    -6.73098    0.764833    Chr1:1
c1.21   SNP2    -4.871  0.00393002  Chr1:101
c1.12   SNP3    -0.766822   0.0891227   Chr1:201
c1.22   SNP4    11.7499 0.141861    Chr1:301
c2.11   SNP5    8.38008 0.741379    Chr1:401
c2.21   SNP6    -0.86974    0.00824037  Chr1:501
c2.12   SNP7    -0.181898   0.00494422  Chr1:601
c2.22   SNP8    -7.32856    0.245436    Chr1:701
c3.11   SNP9    -12.0418    0.369929    Chr1:801
c3.12   SNP10   11.2833 0.357378    Chr1:901
c3.22   SNP11   -0.0308993  0.270918    Chr1:1001
c4.121  SNP12   1.51586 0.0770791   Chr1:1101
c4.122  SNP13   0.118888    0.0742901   Chr1:1201
```

What I want to do is to accumulate values within third column in which are belong to the same group from the first column. for example the first 4 values are belonged to the group c1, while the next 4 values are belonged to group c2 and ... . So the new output should look like:

```
 Output :
c1 -0.61778
c2  0.00845
c3 -0.7875
c4 1.6347
```

Any suggestion please? (please consider that the real data is huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`perl` solution, assumes input file is sorted by c1, c2, etc.. So, saving in hash/array is not required

```
$ perl -lane '
$F[0] =~ s/\..*//;
if($F[0] ne $p && $. > 1)
{
    print "$p $sum";
    $sum = 0;
}
$sum += $F[2];
$p = $F[0];
END { print "$p $sum" }' ip.txt
c1 -0.618902
c2 -0.000118000000001395
c3 -0.7893993
c4 1.634748
```

- `-la` strip newlines from input and add while printing, split input line on spaces and save to `@F` array
- `$F[0] =~ s/\..*//` delete all characters from `.` for first field
- `if($F[0] ne $p && $. > 1)` if input line number is not first line and first field is not the same as previous one

  - print field name and accumulated sum, clear sum variable
- At end, print again to account for last entry

Another way would be to not split the input line and use regex to extract required key and value:

```
$ perl -lne '
($k, $v) = /^([^.]+)(?:\S+\s+){2}(\S+)/;
if($k ne $p && $. > 1)
{
    print "$p $sum";
    $sum = 0;
}
$sum += $v;
$p = $k;
END { print "$p $sum" }' ip.txt
c1 -0.618902
c2 -0.000118000000001395
c3 -0.7893993
c4 1.634748
```

Answer (score 3):

With [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) (after replacing the period with whitespace using `sed`)

```
sed 's/\./ /' data | datamash -W groupby 1 sum 4
c1      -0.618902
c2      -0.000118
c3      -0.7893993
c4      1.634748
```

Comment: just downloaded and tried it out.. fyi: on version 1.0.7, had to use `-g1` instead of `groupby 1`

Comment: -bash: datamash: command not found
I got this error. why is that?

Comment: @zara presumably the `datamash` software is not installed, or is not in your executable search `PATH`? It isn't (yet) a standard Unix utility.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk '{grp = gensub("^([^.]+).*", "\\1", 1, $1); \
              arr[grp]+=$3} END {for (i in arr) print i, arr[i]}' file.txt
```

- `gensub("^([^.]+).*", "\\1", 1, $1)` gets the portion before first `.` from first field, we are storing it as variable `grp`
- `arr[grp]+=$3` generates array with key as `grp`, and values are accumulated from third column of each line
- The chunk in `END` segment will iterate over the array elements, and print key-values in desired format

For consistent input, with POSIX `awk`:

```
awk '{sub("\\..*", "", $1); arr[$1]+=$3} END {for (i in arr) print i, arr[i]}'
```

- `sub("\\..*", "", $1)` modifies the first field in place to truncate the portion after `.`, and array `arr` is created with keys as the (modified) first field

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
c1.11   SNP1    -6.73098    0.764833    Chr1:1
c1.21   SNP2    -4.871  0.00393002  Chr1:101
c1.12   SNP3    -0.766822   0.0891227   Chr1:201
c1.22   SNP4    11.7499 0.141861    Chr1:301
c2.11   SNP5    8.38008 0.741379    Chr1:401
c2.21   SNP6    -0.86974    0.00824037  Chr1:501
c2.12   SNP7    -0.181898   0.00494422  Chr1:601
c2.22   SNP8    -7.32856    0.245436    Chr1:701
c3.11   SNP9    -12.0418    0.369929    Chr1:801
c3.12   SNP10   11.2833 0.357378    Chr1:901
c3.22   SNP11   -0.0308993  0.270918    Chr1:1001
c4.121  SNP12   1.51586 0.0770791   Chr1:1101
c4.122  SNP13   0.118888    0.0742901   Chr1:1201

% awk '{grp = gensub("^([^.]+).*", "\\1", 1, $1); arr[grp]+=$3} END {for (i in arr) print i, arr[i]}' file.txt
c1 -0.618902
c2 -0.000118
c3 -0.789399
c4 1.63475

% awk '{sub("\\..*", "", $1); arr[$1]+=$3} END {for (i in arr) print i, arr[i]}' file.txt
c1 -0.618902
c2 -0.000118
c3 -0.789399
c4 1.63475
```

Comment: this method changes the order of groups in output for the real data.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution, try it and let me know if it works.

```
#!/bin/bash


awk '
BEGIN{group="c1"
sum=0}
{
    if(substr($1,1,2)==group) 
    {sum+=$3
    print group " " sum} 
    else {
        group=substr($1,1,2)
        sum=$3
        print group " " sum}
    }'  file.txt > tmp.txt





awk 'BEGIN{group="c1"}
     $1!=group {print group " " sum
     group=$1} {sum=$2}
     END{print $1 " " $2}'  tmp.txt >finalResult.txt

rm tmp.txt
```

And the result should appear in finalResult.txt. You can copy it into a bash script and test it.